# meaning of 一人じゃ

Tags: words

I'm familiar with 一人じゃない, but I'm not sure what 一人じゃ means. Is it a contracted version?

I found the word in this context below:

> 一人じゃ運べそうもないから、手伝ってくれる？
>   *(Since it seems like I'm unable to carry it by myself, could you help me?)*

Comment: Without any further context, I would read じゃ as a colloquialism for だ.  Hence, 一人じゃ would just mean "I'm alone"

Comment: Will you provide the context? じゃ can be では (as in **一人じゃ**無理だ。) or だ (as in ここにいるのはわし**一人じゃ**。)

Comment: @chocolate additional context has been added :) From the sentence, I'm pretty sure it means (by oneself/alone). I just want to confirm if there was a contracted version of 一人じゃない since I cannot search it up online anywhere :) Thanks for the additional information about だ (from your example, I understand that it act like an accent).

Comment: `Since it seems it cannot be carried by yourself, would you like me to help you?` <- The subject of 一人じゃ運べそうもない is the speaker (=I), and the subject of 手伝ってくれる is the hearer (=you), so it'd be like "Since it seems **I** cannot carry it by myself, would **you** help me?"

Comment: Regarding your comment at the bottom of the edited question: this post even closed won't be deleted and will stay searchable. Moreover, marked as duplicate it will point those who searched for the phrase to a well written answer. If it got reopened, it would only allow posting more answers here and in effect make search more troublesome and confusing.

Comment: @macraf ah i see. I'm new so i don't really understand how it worked, thanks for taking your time to explain it for me :)

Comment: @chocolate i was hesitant too, thanks for explaining the correct meaning, will revised it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1人じゃない = 1人ではありません。
Consider that the negative form of “です" is “ではありません",which can also be “じゃありません"
So I think “じゃ” is used as a simple form of"では".